# FB.login not firing in Facebook Mobile Web Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am Unable to take the Permissions Dialog as well as Login to Facebook here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body> 


<div data-role="page">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
  };

function handleStatusChange(response) {
     document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';

     if (response.authResponse) {
     //  console.log(response);
     FB.api('/me/likes/171099129606813', function(response) {
                        if ( response.data.length === 1 ) { //there should only be a single value inside "data"
                        console.log('You like it');
                        } else {
                        console.log("You don't like it");
                        }
        });

     }
     else
     {
         FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                  //console.log(response); 

                    FB.api('/me/likes/171099129606813', function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                     });

                } else {
                    alert('Not Logged In');
                  // user is not logged in
                }    

        }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});     
     }
   }
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

still its not taking me to authentication page it is changing the class name of body but not working on fb login

Comment: FB.login should only be called upon explicit user interaction (like f.e. clicking on an link), _and_ not nested in other asynchronous function callbacks, because doing otherwise makes it much more likely to be blocked by the browser’s popup blocker.

Comment: Any reason why you used the JS SDK location in the channel file property (rather than as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ )?

Comment: Also are you sure you weren't already authenticated with this app? Try going to your Facebook account settings (under 'Apps') and remove it. PS your code above works perfectly for me, with a virgin app id.

Answer (score 0):

It took me today a while to understand that window.fbAsyncInit method is not fired on some mobile browsers (in fact on all mobile devices in my company). What you need to do is to add sth like this:

```
var called = false;
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    if (called) return;
    called = true;

    // here the fb code
}

if (!called) window.fbAsyncInit();
```

Comment: That sounds odd - fbAsyncInit /should/ be called no matter the environment. Are you sure jQuery Mobile isn't doing something funky with your page? Try moving the script tag outside of the 'page' context.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. The FB.login function was nested in a callback. In my case the browser was blocking the popup page from facebook. When I unblocked popups, it came up fine.